# How to react to a message by Id

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have the id of a message stored in my database, the message content is a request. After fullfilling the request I want to add a reaction to this message.

What I need is something like:

```
  message.get('OLD_MESSAGE_ID').react("");
```

But I've no idea how to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the text channel the message is in.

```
var channel = guild.channels.get("CHANNEL_ID")

channel.fetchMessage("OLD_MESSAGE_ID")
 .then((message) => {

  message.react("")

 })
```

Comment: I'm getting on channel.fetchMessage: SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Comment: Ok, it was because guid was not defined. Now it's solved. Thank you!